# Como customizar circular progressbar android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Estoy tratando de implementar un progressbar custom a mi proyecto android, el cual tiene un estilo muy particular, el cual no he podido replicar en el xml, verán este cuenta con una serie de cuatro colores que representan un estado X del progreso del flujo del trabajo, estos colores deben estar predefinido y un punto indicador donde muestre en que porcentaje se encuentra este flujo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene que ser así, donde los colores son fijos y agregar ese indicador donde se ubica el porcentaje, alguien sabe como puedo hacer eso asi? ¿existe una librería que me permita hacer eso?

Actualmente he realizado el siguiente codigo, pero el resultado no es el esperado en términos de como mostrar los colores

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="16"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#DDD"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <gradient
                android:gradientRadius="50"
                android:startColor="@color/green"
                android:centerColor="@color/yellow"
                android:endColor="@color/orange"
                android:type="sweep"
                />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

El resultado es el siguiente, como ven difiere de como es el esperado ya que con el gradient hace una "fusión" de los colores y no los muestra como un corte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería bueno que coloques lo que has avanzado de código.

Comment: Ya agregue mas detalles de lo que llevo